# Tracking between blog and webshop on same domain

Tags: google-analytics

I have a webshop (Magento) on mysite.com.
I have a blog (wordpress.org) setup on mysite.com/blog

My goal is to setup tracking in such a way that I can see data for the blog and separate data for the webshop. I am doing this now by using separate profiles, and using exclude filters.

However, I still want to be able to see if visitors to the blog end up buying anything in the webshop. How could I do that? I have a feeling the exclude filter prevents this.

I have investigated advanced segments, but no luck. Also _setCookiePath, I have no idea what effect that will have...

So, any GA experts out there? :)

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want two profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one profile and the same GA code. It will help to decipher the data.

If you want to track your blog visitors, a custom segment can do the trick. This is what I do and my site spans across Moodle, WordPress and PHPBB.

That way, you can even track Magento conversions which originated from your WordPress blog.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way for you to find these conevsions, is to setup the GOAL feature in your Google Analytics account.

Then you will still be using the same GA code and you are also able to specify various path´s the the goals you set up.